# ST_GEOGFROMTEXT Multipolygons converted to Polygons BigQuery

Tags: polygon, geography, multi-polygon

My table contains multipolygons in column called BoundaryWKT, which is in a string format. I used function `ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(BoundaryWKT)` to convert column of multipolygons from ****string** format to a **geography** format**.
After running the query, **all multipolygons were converted to polygons**. Does anyone know why this happens? Is it possible to convert polygons back to multipolygons? For me it is necessarily to keep the data as multipolygons, otherwise connecting GPS coordinates to (multi)polygons fails at certain points.

**INPUT** (string format):
[image]

**Function:**

```
SELECT ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(BoundaryWKT) As BoundaryWKT1
from `xx.yy.zz`
```

**OUTPUT** (geography format):

[image]

Comment: what do your input strings look like?

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: PostGIS has [ST_Multi](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html) for this -- check your docs to see if there is a similar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input Multipolygon in the example has a single polygon in it, as it only contains a single loop: `MULTIPOLYGON(((.....)))`. A multi-polygon with multiple polygons would look like `MULTIPOLYGON(((.....)), ((.....)))`. The latter would be preserved as multipolygon, but BQ treats the former as simple polygon.

> Is it possible to convert polygons back to multipolygons?

Depends on what is the purpose of this conversion. For all BigQuery computations and SQL queries, there is no difference, and if any query does not work as expected - the reason is something else.

If you want to get the shape text as MULTIPOLYGON, the easiest is to create a stored proc to make polygons MULTI:

```
create temp function ST_MakeMultiStr(geo STRING) RETURNS STRING AS (
CASE
    WHEN STARTS_WITH(geo, 'POLYGON') THEN CONCAT(REPLACE(geo, 'POLYGON', 'MULTIPOLYGON('), ')')
    ELSE geo
END);

create temp function ST_MakeMulti(geo GEOGRAPHY) RETURNS STRING AS
(ST_MakeMultiStr(ST_AsText(geo)));

SELECT ST_MakeMulti(geo) FROM
UNNEST([
  ST_GeogFromText('point(1 2)'), 
  ST_GeogFromText('multipoint(1 2, 2 3)'), 
  ST_GeogFromText('Polygon((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 1))'),
  ST_GeogFromText('MultiPolygon(((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 1)))')
  ])  geo;
```

Comment: I thought conversion from multipolygons to polygons was the reason to this problem:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372443/sql-bigquery-st-contains-geography-and-python-visualization-mismatch?noredirect=1#comment608332_372443

Comment: It probably is not. In spatial terms, `MULTIPOLYGON(((...)))` and `POLYGON((...))` are identical, if the contents (...) are the same.

Comment: I don't think "the latter is preserved as a multipolygon" is true, e.g. `select st_geogfromtext("MULTIPOLYGON(((2 2, 2 -2, -2 -2, -2 2, 2 2)),((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 1)))")` returns `POLYGON((1 2.00091355021717, -2 2, -2 -2, 2 -2, 2 1.00015229710421, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 2.00091355021717))` with very odd rounding errors

Comment: Also point (1 2) appears from nowhere in the results above :-\

Comment: @Qrilka - this MULTIPOLYGON contains two overlapping polygons. This is not allowed by SQL/MM or ISO standards. So all systems have to fix it one way or another before using it. E.g. PostGIS ST_MakeValid removes the overlapping part, producing two smaller polygons. BigQuery dissolves the polygons instead (similar to PostGIS's st_unaryunion). The "rounding errors" are due to BigQuery GEOGRAPHY working on a sphere and using geodesic, rather than planar, edges, which gives you `1 2.00091355021717` instead of `1 2`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I didn't think about overlapping, as for rounding - `st_geogfromgeojson('{ "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates":[[[[2, 2], [2, -2], [-2, -2], [-2, 2], [2, 2]]],[[[1, 1], [3,1], [3, 3], [1, 3], [1, 1]]]]}')` with equivalent input but in GeoJSON and BigQuery returns only integers, namely `POLYGON((2 1, 3 1, 3 3, 2.5 3, 2 3, 1.5 3, 1 3, 1 2, 0 2, -1 2, -2 2, -2 -2, -1 -2, 0 -2, 1 -2, 2 -2, 2 1))`

Comment: Yes, the GeoJSON is interpreted according to the standard - GeoJSON uses planar edges, so when reading it BigQuery approximates planar edges with the geodesic edges that BQ uses. It does it by tessellating (adding vertices) as described in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#coordinate_systems_and_edges. In this case the tessellation point got right in the intersection, so it looks precise. In other cases you would still get "rounding errors" - try replacing all "3" with "4" in your input.